# Which is the best way to use gRPC with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, grpc

I am starting to learn gRPC and I would like to know know how to use with Entity Framework Core.

I have an application that for one side I have the client that ask to the service for some data in the database. Then the service use entity core to get the data and send it to the client. The process it is in this way:

client --> request to service --> service request to Entity Framework Core --> Entity Framework Core give to service the data --> the service send the data to the client.

My doubt is the communitcation between the service and entity core. With Entity Framework Core I work with POCO entities, but I know that gRPC works with messages, so I am wondering if I have to convert the data from POCO entities to messages of gRPC.

If this is the case, to maintenace the application it can be a bit hard, because if I do a change in my database (I am working in a database first way), I have to modify my POCO entities and later again modify the messages of gRPC.

But also I have another doubt. A POCO entity can have related entities, sometimes in collections, beacuse I need to include them in the query in Entity Framework Core. So if I have to create methods to copy the information from POCO entities to message to gRPC, and also I have to program all the logic to copy also the related entities, that also this realted entities can have another related entities, it can be a very big work.

So I am wondering if wouldn't be a better option instead of copy the data from POCO entities to messages, or how it is the way to work with gRPC and Entity Framework Core.

Comment: gRPC is a networking protocol, EF is a data access library. They aren't related. You already have to translate database DTOs to REST/HTTP API DTOs simply because the database, domain and API schemas don't match. Different concerns, different scenarios, different use cases result in different schemas

Comment: A well designed database schema can handle many different cases. A well designed API DTO is only meant to serve a single case. If you use DDD, the domain classes used between the HTTP and database are specific to the domain logic (as they should be)